# display changing list of disabled options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery which disables a list of select options (across multiple drop downs).

I'm trying to get a list of these disabled options. I'm failing to get the list to update when the options change, my list currently just keeps populating the new disabled options and doesn't remove the newly re-enabled options.

Please help: http://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/y858g/2/

```
$(function () {
var previous;

$(".openTeam").on('focus', function () {
    // Store the current value on focus and on change
    previous = this.value;
}).on('change', function () {
    var excludedPlayers = '';

    // Get the filter value
    var filterVal = $(this).val().substr(0, 3);
    var selector = 'option[value^="' + filterVal + '"]';

    others = $('.openTeam').not(this).find(selector);
    others.prop('disabled', true);

    // Now loop through and enable previous
    var oldFilterVal = previous.substr(0, 3);
    var oldSelector = 'option[value^="' + oldFilterVal + '"]';

    $('.openTeam').find(oldSelector).prop('disabled', false);

    //FAILED ATTEMPT 1:
    //var test = $('#warning-message > div').find(oldSelector).remove();

    //FAILED ATTEMPT 2:
    /*
    var disabledPlayers = $('.openTeam option:disabled').val();      
    $('#warning-message').append('<div value="' + disabledPlayers + '">' + disabledPlayers + '</div>');
    */

    var myArray = others.text().split(')');

    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        $('#warning-message').append('<div value="' + myArray[i] + ')' + '">' + myArray[i] + ')</div>');
    };

});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, there are a couple of things I might change. First, I would bind the assignment of the `previous` variable not to just the focus event, but also the click event. Otherwise, changing a selected player while the list is already in focus will not change the previous variable, resulting in problems with re-enabling the previously disabled players. So, your event bindings would look something like this:

```
$(".openTeam").on('click focus', function () {
    ...
}).on('change', function () {
    ...
});
```

Now, for the updating the list of disabled players...I liked your second unsuccessful approach best, so I decided to expand on it (hope you don't mind that I abandoned your most recent attempt!). Mainly, just making use of jQuery's `.empty()` and `.each()` to clear out the original list, then iterate through each `<option>` to generate a new list of disabled players:

```
$('#warning-message').empty();
var disabledPlayers = $('.openTeam option:disabled');
console.log(disabledPlayers.length);
disabledPlayers.each(function(){
    $('#warning-message').append('<div value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</div>');
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y858g/18/) showing the code all implemented. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.